# Asp core, Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Repository pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, repository, repository-pattern

I am working on an asp core 1.1 and i want to create a `select` repository pattern in my project.

**my code in repository class :**

```
public class AuthorReposetory : IDisposable
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AuthorReposetory(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }




    public static List<Author> GetAuthorList()
    {
        List<Author> model = new List<Author>();

        model = _context.authors.Select(a => new Author
        {
            AuthorId = a.AuthorId,
            AuthorName = a.AuthorName,
            AuthorDescription = a.AuthorDescription
        }).ToList();

        return model;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    ~AuthorReposetory()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

**and in controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var q = AuthorReposetory.GetAuthorList();
    return View(q);
}
```

**Update**

**Here is my StartUp Class**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //define Connection string
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefualtConnection")));
        //For Create and use identity in database
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddPaging();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {

            //New Area For Admin
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            //New Area For User
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "UserProfile",
                template: "{area:exists}/{controller=UserProfile}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            //tranditional Routing
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

**My Connection string in appsettings.json**

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefualtConnection" : "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;User ID = sa; Password = 123"
  },





  "Logging": {
   "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
     "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` when run `model = _context.authors.Select(a => new Author` in repository.
In the above i show controller code, Repository class code and start up code to figure out.
Where can the problem be?

**Note : everything is good in controller. just problem is in repository class.**

Comment: show your starup class where you configure context

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I add it to my question

Comment: might be the connection string is not correct, as you have DBContext configure in the startup

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Do I need to put code of the connection?

Comment: Why is your `_context` static in `AuthorRepository`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using static methods and the constructor is never called as you never create the object. You would have to change your constructor to:

```
public static AuthorReposetory()
{
    _context = new ApplicationDbContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefualtConnection")));
}
```

but that's quite bad practice since you have to setup the connection in the constructor and this also created a hard dependency on your context class.

A better solution would be to create a non static class

```
public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public AuthorRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // ...
}

public interface IAuthorRepository
{
    // ...
}
```

Reverse the dependency with injection:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //define Connection string and setup dependency injection
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefualtConnection")));
    services.AddScoped<IAuthorRepository, AuthorRepository>();
    // ...
}
```

Controller:

```
public HomeController
{
    private IAuthorRepository _authorRepository;

    public HomeController(IAuthorRepository authorRepository)
    {
        _authorRepository = authorRepository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var q = _autorRepository.GetAuthorList();
        return View(q);
    }
}
```

Comment: `services.AddDbContext()` registers the DbContext in DI.  There's no need to do it again.  And it's best to add the repositories as Scoped, not Transient.

Comment: @Brad true that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your _context object is null. How is your DI/IoC configured? I would investigate in that way.

Your db context should be added like this :

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db"));
}

Here is the documentation on how to configure your db context: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: @hix my context works without repository and in controller but when i use it in repository class not works, any idea to solve it?

Comment: Well, I  can not see any controller or repository in your configuration. Include them, and your solution will work ;)  I think that the exception occurs when you make a call to your AuthorReposetory class from your controller.

Comment: And please do not put an exception in the dispose method. It is like you shoot yourself in the head :)

Comment: I don`t know what I have to do exactly ?

Comment: You have to add your repo, and service classes into dependency injection. You can do that in the ConfigureServices method in your startup class. The syntax is like : services.AddTransient<TMyInterface>(TMyInterfaceImplementation);

Comment: @saeed put break point in repository constructor and check if context is being set

Comment: It won't call your constructor. It is not aware of its existence. You have to tell the engine what I have mentioned above.

Comment: @Hix in which class shoud i change?

Comment: I told you already: 
You have to add your repo, and service classes into dependency injection. You can do that in the ConfigureServices method in your startup class. The syntax is like : services.AddTransient<TMyInterface, TMyInterfaceImplementation>();

Comment: you need to register your repository class in container

Answer (score 0):

You have not registered your repository class in the `services` so it is not getting resolved via the container. In your `ConfigureServices` method try this:

```
services.AddScoped<AuthorReposetory>();
```

Comment: I add it to `ConfigureServcies` but Repository constructor not work again

Comment: this should work i think, may be you have something else missing too

Comment: maybe i sholud create a new instance of repository in controller to use it